# Cupy slower than numpy when doing a "for loop" for columns of an array as vectors

Tags: cupy

I'm trying to parallelize the following operation with cupy:
I have an array. For each column of that array, I'm generating 2 random vectors. I take that array column, add one of the vectors, subtract the other, and make that new vector the next column of the array. I continue on until I finish with the array.

I already asked the following question - [Cupy slower than numpy when iterating through array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57386330/cupy-slower-than-numpy-when-iterating-through-array). But this is different, in that I believe I followed the advice of parallelizing the operation and having one "for loop" instead of two, and iterating only through the array columns instead of both rows and columns.

```
import cupy as cp
import time
#import numpy as cp


def row_size(array):
    return(array.shape[1])

def number_of_rows(array):
    return(array.shape[0])

x = (cp.zeros((200,200), 'f'))
#x = cp.zeros((200,200))

x[:,1] = 500000

vector_one = x * 0
vector_two = x * 0

start = time.time()
for i in range(number_of_rows(x) - 1):
    if sum(x[ :, i])!=0:
        vector_one[ :, i + 1], vector_two[ :, i+ 1] = cp.random.poisson(.01*x[:,i],len(x[:,i])), cp.random.poisson(.01 * x[:,i],len(x[:,i]))
        x[ :, i+ 1] = x[ :, i] + vector_one[ :, i+ 1] - vector_two[ :, i+ 1]

 time = time.time() - start      
 print(x)
 print(time)
```

When I run this in cupy, the time comes out to about .62 seconds.

When I switch to numpy, so I 1) uncomment #import numpy as cp and #x = cp.zeros((200,200)) and 2) instead comment import cupy as cp 
and x = (cp.zeros((200,200), 'f')):

The time comes out to about .11 seconds.

I thought maybe if I increase the array size, for example from (200,200) to (2000,2000), then I'd see a difference in cupy being faster, but it's still slower.

I know this is working properly, in a sense, because if I change the coefficient in cp.random.poisson from .01 to .5, I can only do that in cupy because that lambda is too large for numpy.

But still, how do I make it actually faster with cupy?

Answer (score 2):

In general, looping on the host (CPU) and iteratively processing small device (GPU) arrays isn't ideal due to the larger number of separate kernels you will have to launch than in a columnar-oriented approach. However, sometimes a columnar-oriented approach just isn't feasible.

You can speed up your CuPy code by using CuPy's `sum` instead of using Python's built-in `sum` operation, which is forcing a device to host transfer each time you call it. With that said, you can also speed up your NumPy code by switching to NumPy's sum.

```py
import cupy as cp
import time
#import numpy as cp


def row_size(array):
    return(array.shape[1])

def number_of_rows(array):
    return(array.shape[0])

x = (cp.zeros((200,200), 'f'))
#x = cp.zeros((200,200))

x[:,1] = 500000

vector_one = x * 0
vector_two = x * 0

start = time.time()
for i in range(number_of_rows(x) - 1):
#     if sum(x[ :, i]) !=0:
    if x[ :, i].sum() !=0: # or you could do: if x[ :, i].sum().get() !=0:
        vector_one[ :, i + 1], vector_two[ :, i+ 1] = cp.random.poisson(.01*x[:,i],len(x[:,i])), cp.random.poisson(.01 * x[:,i],len(x[:,i]))
        x[ :, i+ 1] = x[ :, i] + vector_one[ :, i+ 1] - vector_two[ :, i+ 1]

cp.cuda.Device().synchronize() # CuPy is asynchronous, but this doesn't really affect the timing here.

t = time.time() - start      
print(x)
print(t)
[[     0. 500000. 500101. ... 498121. 497922. 497740.]
 [     0. 500000. 499894. ... 502050. 502174. 502112.]
 [     0. 500000. 499989. ... 501703. 501836. 502081.]
 ...
 [     0. 500000. 499804. ... 499600. 499526. 499371.]
 [     0. 500000. 499923. ... 500371. 500184. 500247.]
 [     0. 500000. 500007. ... 501172. 501113. 501254.]]
0.06389498710632324
```

This small change should make your workflow much faster (0.06 vs 0.6 seconds originally on my T4 GPU). Note that the `.get()` method in the comment is used to explicitly transfer the result of the `sum` operation from the GPU to the CPU before the not equal comparison. This isn't necessary, as CuPy knows how to handle logical operations, but would give you a very tiny additional speedup.